# PHP Echo - Escaping quotes

Tags: php, string, echo

I was programming something in PHP but since I'm a newbie I got stuck.

I have no clue how should I escape quotes on the following line. Moreover, I think the PHP tags inside echo are incorrect. How should I change this to make it work?

```
echo '<tr onclick="DoNav('list.php?id=<? echo(".$row['ID']."); ?>');">';
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape with a backslash, use "." for concatenation.

```
$row = array();
$row['ID'] = 1;

echo '<tr onclick="DoNav(\'list.php?id=' . $row['ID']. '\');">';
```

Output

```
<tr onclick="DoNav('list.php?id=1');">
```

Also make sure to escape any content you're going to use in Javascript or HTML. For an ID, you might just cast as an integer:

```
echo '<tr onclick="DoNav(\'list.php?id=' . (int)$row['ID']. '\');">';
```

Strings'll be more important to escape.

Answer (score 1):

The general/common escape character is `\`, works in PHP and Javascript.

```
echo '<tr onclick="DoNav(\'list.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '\');">';
```

Answer (score 0):

This u need

```
echo '<tr onclick="DoNav(\'list.php?id='.$row['ID'].'\');">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am boot sure what DoNav does but I think you want to have this line instead:

```
echo '<tr onclick="DoNav(\'list.php?id=' . $row['ID']. '\');">';
```

In PHP the \ is the escape character. If you want to escape a " you can write \"

I hope it was helpful. Good luck