# print one quote by echo method - php

Tags: php, echo, quote

This is my code

```
echo'

<td class="success"><button  id="btn-Preview-Image" class="btn btn-success" name="sure" onClick="PrintElem('.'mydiv'.$row['id'].''.');">print</button></td>

';
```

the onclick method printed like this

```
onClick="PrintElem(mydiv12);"
```

but I want it like this with one quote

```
 onClick="PrintElem('mydiv12');"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Echo - Escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593049/php-echo-escaping-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrap the single quote between double

```
echo '<td class="success">
        <button  id="btn-Preview-Image" class="btn btn-success" name="sure" 
        onClick="PrintElem(' . "'mydiv".$row['id'] ."'" . ');">print</button>
        </td>';
```

Comment: can you explain how ?

Comment: Yes .. just each time you concat a string you can use both double and single quoye for build the string you need  .. in this case just  using the sequence ."'mydiv". as you can se the double quote can easyly manage the single quote

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by adding and escaping single quotes as such:

```
// $row['id'] = "123";
('.'\'mydiv'.$row['id'].'\''.')
```

Result (from HTML source):

```
onClick="PrintElem('mydiv123')
```

---

Side note: This being another way. I hadn't seen the (other) answer when I posted this.

Comment: You can even simplify it slightly: `(\'mydiv'. $row['id'] . '\')`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Plus, your method uses less characters. Side note: Not taking away from the other answer of course.